# How to make AngularJS slider work with angular ui tabs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I would like to add a AngularJS slider (http://prajwalkman.github.io/angular-slider/) inside of a angular ui tab (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs). However, the slider does not work when placed inside the angular ui tab (the slider works fine outside of a tab directive). Can someone suggest a solution or workaround to get the slider to work in a tab?

Comment: I would suspect a scoping issue since tabs are creating a new scope. Or some CSS issue. But really, impossible to say more without a minimal reproduce scenario (ideally using plunk).